# How can I play sound on two separate sound cards with SDL?

Tags: c++, windows, audio, sdl, sdl-mixer

I have two sound cards on my machine, and I'm developing an application playing sounds via SDL_mixer. I want some of these sounds played on first card and some on others. How can I achieve that in Windows?

It doesn't even have to be a single instance. I have two instances running with different enviroment (AUDIODEV) in Linux and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is in [roadmap](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/Roadmap) for current (June 2013) release-candidate SDL 2.0.